# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

i am not programmer but i like things with automation and still learning about it. Please advise me.

Here is my problem:
I used Python Selenium to login this website anywhereconference.com and tried to login with moderator mode but those element was not found. The problem is, the login container is hidden under moderator container and need to click first.

**Code**

```
ntt = webdriver.Chrome()

ntt.get("https://anywhereconference.com")

ntt.set_window_size(1500, 800)

ntt.implicitly_wait(10)

mode = ntt.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="arka-login-moderator-type-button-header"]').click()

login = ntt.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="arka-login-moderator-weblogin"]')

login.send_keys('XXX')

login.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**Error**

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="arka-login-moderator-type-button-header"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

**Click element**

```
div id="arka-login-moderator" class="arka-login-button arka-login-moderator-button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right arka-login-moderator-selected ui-state-active ready">

    <span class="ui-button-text">
        div id="arka-login-moderator-type-button-header" class="arka-login-type-button-header">I'm a moderator / admin</div
        div id="arka-login-moderator-type-button-text" class="arka-login-type-button-text">Start or schedule a meeting</div
    </span>
```

[Login Page Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvsY3.png)

i also try to used another method but still same but using Selenium IDE extension no problem.

**Example 1**

```
WebDriverWait(ntt, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id='arka-login-moderator-type-button-header']")))
.click()
```

**Example 2 JavaScript**

```
mode = ntt.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="arka-login-moderator-type-button-header"]')
    .click()
    ntt.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", mode)
```

Comment: For starters, you are missing a bunch of opening and closing tags. I tried to format your code more readable. For example in Click element your `<div>` has no starting `<`. please make sure you start and close all tags properly

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion . i removed the "<div" because its read as function on here and i am not sure how to use the code block yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, iframe is present on your page you need to switch ifraame first before dealing with your web elements :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.anywhereconference.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'globalFrameCenter')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='arka-login-moderator']//span"))).click()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='arka-login-moderator-weblogin']"))).send_keys("Test")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='arka-login-moderator-pin']"))).send_keys("Test")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your xpath as follows

```
mode = ntt.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='arka-login-moderator-type-button-header']").click()

login = ntt.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='arka-login-moderator-weblogin']")
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the error still the same to locate the element even if i edited the quotes.